# TL494 step-down converter high voltage LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, buck, step-down, tl494

I have tried to make LTSpice of step down DC-DC converter, however I cannot get it to work. I suspect the schematic is good however either LTSpice model is not correct or I made some critical mistake.

Models used are:
TL494: https://www.mkdynamics.net/current_projects/current_projects_electronics_hacking_TL494_LTSpice_model.html

IRS21271 (converted from pspice):
[https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/irs21271s/?tab=~%27simulation_models#!designsupport](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/irs21271s/?tab=%7E%27simulation_models#!designsupport)

Here is the schematic:

[image]

Now I cannot get it to stabilize at 12 V as it's supposed to. MOSFET driver seems to be working (blue input, green output):

[image]

Output seems to "stabilize" but at a way lower voltage than expected:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the entire schematic: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/xosaliyexu.sql

Comment: High-side driver config looks wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an N channel MOSFET and that requires a driver that is boot-strapped: -

[image]

Unfortunately, you don't appear to have implemented boot-strapping correctly. For instance, consider this circuit taken from the [data sheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRS2127PBF-DataSheet-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356768e7a27c0): -

[image]

I've highlighted Vs because this needs to connect to the source of the MOSFET to achieve proper boot-strapping of the gate driver. You have it connected to 0 volts and this inevitably means that the gate of the power MOSFET will only be driven to 12 volts.

Given that you require a 12 volt output, you need the gate to be driven to something like 24 volts to adequately turn-on the MOSFET. Proper boot-strapping ensures this.

Comment: Indeed you are correct however with that configuration, ltspice does not want to run at all, takes like 10ns per second making it extremely slow

Comment: @Kaminari sounds like a new issue to me; we don't like to escalate new unrelated problems onto the original question so, my advice is this: check what the maximum time step is that LTspice is using and, if that doesn't solve the problem (by making it bigger; maybe 100 ns), ask a new question and, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something relating to your original question, then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: Not sure what to do to be honest because i tried many many things to get this circuit to working, should i just edit main question?

Comment: No, the new problem requires a new question and, raising a new question opens things up to the whole community @Kaminari

Comment: Accepting this answer then and posting new question

Comment: That's the best way as I see it @Kaminari and, make sure your schematic is accurate and that you explain that you have tried different settings in LTspice. I'm no expert on LTspice so, further additions here would not have proven useful. Let an expert on LTspice answer it.